# The import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices

I am developing the Microservices code by taking reference from https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-microservices. I was able to successfully run all the modules, but I'm getting the below error.

> The import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer cannot be resolved

From the `spring-petclinic-admin-server` module, I am getting the below error.

```
import de.codecentric.boot.admin.server.config.EnableAdminServer;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAdminServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class SpringBootAdminApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

I was able to start the other **microservices** modules.

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-petclinic-microservices</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.0.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <docker.image.exposed.port>9090</docker.image.exposed.port>
        <docker.image.dockerfile.dir>${basedir}/../docker</docker.image.dockerfile.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Admin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-server-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Third-party librairies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the link : https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/. I have added below dependencies, then it works well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```